# How to install "import" package in VSCode for LaTeX

Tags: packages, installing, import

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have VSCode with Latex-workshop extension installed. I had made some changes in my system, because of which I lost the "import" Latex packages I had installed. I am unable to figure out how to install it again. I keep getting `! LaTeX Error: File 'import.sty' not found.`

I have been trying for ages; I downloaded import from CTAN and unzipped it in a folder that seemed to contain all other Latex packages, but nothing. I use `Latexmk` and `pdflatex`. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: Which OS are you using ? Have tried to install the complete TexLive distribution ?

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux - 2. It has Ubuntu 18.04. No, I haven't done that, I use the latex-workshop extension.

Comment: As far as I understand, Latex-workshop extension is just a module for VSCode and does nothing with your installation. So here is the way I would proceed to locate the origin of your problem: 1. Verify your LaTeX and 'import' install, you can do it in your terminal 2. If there is an issue with step I would suggest to install the complete TexLive distribution for simplicity and restart to step 1, then 3. Verify the settings of Latex-workshop and specially the path variables.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to verify my import and latex installation? Thanks

Comment: Create a Minimal Example (cf my first comment) containing `\usepackage{import}` then compile it through your terminal in the folder of your file with the command: `pdflatex name_of_your_MWE.tex`